# What items carry over into New Game+?

Tags: the-last-of-us

Which parts of the game are carried over into the New Game+ mode, once you've completed the game.

Comment: haven't beaten it yet so I'll just leave a comment, I think I read somewhere it was all modded weapons and skill ugprades, but you CAN'T play NG+ at a higher difficult setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your Health
- Stats such as increased health, increased time for crafting items etc.
- Your collectibles
- Weapon Upgrades
- Crafting Levels
- Unspent pills